# C Function to Add Matrices

Tags: c, matrix

I'm new to coding and am currently learning C at school. I had a question regarding how to add matrices in C using a function. I'm facing some difficulties and was hoping to get some words of advice here. The conditions that my instructor gave the class are 1) two 5 x 6 matrices with integer entries from 1 - 100, 2) define and use your own function. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COLUMN 6

size_t addMatrices(int a[][COLUMN], int b[][COLUMN]);
void printArray(int a[][COLUMN]);

int main(void) {
    int row, column;
    int matrix1[ROW][COLUMN] = { {0}, {0} };
    int matrix2[ROW][COLUMN] = { {0}, {0} }; 

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            matrix1[row][column] = 1 + (rand() % 100);
            matrix2[row][column] = 1 + (rand() % 100);
        }
    }

    printf("matrix1:\n");
    printArray(matrix1);
    printf("\n\nmatrix2:\n");
    printArray(matrix2);
    printf("\n\nresult:\n");
    addMatrices(matrix1, matrix2);
    printfArray(result);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
} 

void printArray(int a[][COLUMN]) {
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            printf("%d   ", a[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

size_t addMatrices(int a[][COLUMN], int b[][COLUMN]) {
    int result[ROW][COLUMN] = { {0}, {0} };
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            result[row][column] = a[row][column] + b[row][column];
        }
    } 

    return result;
}
```

If you look at the body of the main method, the compiler says that there's an error because the variable "result" isn't defined when being passed to the function printArray(). I understand the concept of why this error occurs (regarding local variables and passing parameters), but how can I solve this problem?

Aside from this, any other words of advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `int result[ROW][COLUMN] = { {0}, {0} };` move to `main`. and call `void addMatrices(int a[][COLUMN], int b[][COLUMN], int result[][COLUMN]) {`

Comment: You cannot return a locally declared matrix `int result[ROW][COLUMN] = { {0}, {0} };` from a function. It is created on the *function stack* which is **destroyed** on function **return**. Either (1) dynamically allocate `result` or (2) pass it as a parameter to your add function.

Comment: Just an idea: If the compiler complains about an **undefined** variable, maybe _defining_ it might help? Oh, and: C does not support _methods_. And `main` is a _function_ in C++, too.

Comment: As to your last solicitation for comment, you are commended for learning C, there is no finer higher-level language to help you understand coding and develop good skills that will make you a better programmer no matter what language you end up coding in. Understand there is a lot to C, (no pun intended), so the key is to *slow down*, enjoy the learning process, be proactive on sites like this, make friends with the *man pages*, always compile with *warnings enabled* (e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string) and do not accept code until it compiles cleanly without warning or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, you cannot return a locally declared array from a function because the memory for the locally declared array is created on the *function stack* which is destroyed on function **return**. Either declare `result` in `main` and pass as a parameter to `addMatrices` or dynamically allocate storage for `result` in `addMatrices` (so it will survive return) and return a pointer to the beginning of the block of memory and assign it to a pointer in `main`. Declaring `result` in `main` and passing it as a parameter is the easiest thing to do.

Putting those pieces together, you could modify your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COLUMN 6

void addMatrices (int (*a)[COLUMN], int (*b)[COLUMN], int (*res)[COLUMN]);
void printArray (int (*a)[COLUMN]);

int main(void) {
    int row, column;
    int matrix1[ROW][COLUMN] = {{0}};
    int matrix2[ROW][COLUMN] = {{0}}; 
    int result[ROW][COLUMN]  = {{0}};

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            matrix1[row][column] = 1 + (rand() % 100);
            matrix2[row][column] = 1 + (rand() % 100);
        }
    }

    printf ("matrix1:\n");
    printArray (matrix1);
    printf ("\n\nmatrix2:\n");
    printArray (matrix2);
    printf ("\n\nresult:\n");
    addMatrices (matrix1, matrix2, result);
    printArray (result);
    putchar ('\n');  /* don't use printf to print a single character :) */

    return 0;
} 

void printArray(int a[][COLUMN]) {
    int row, column;

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            printf(" %3d", a[row][column]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

void addMatrices (int (*a)[COLUMN], int (*b)[COLUMN], int (*res)[COLUMN])
{
    int row, column;
    if (!a || !b || !res) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid parameter.\n");
        return;
    }

    for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++) {
        for (column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++) {
            res[row][column] = a[row][column] + b[row][column];
        }
    } 
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/addmtrx
matrix1:
  84  78  94  87  50  63
  91  64  41  73  12  68
  83  63  68  30  23  70
  94  12  30  22  85  99
  16  14  92  57  63  97


matrix2:
  87  16  36  93  22  28
  60  27  27  37  69  30
  31  24  36   3  59  68
  57  43  74  20  38  25
  71  27  81  74  71  82


result:
 171  94 130 180  72  91
 151  91  68 110  81  98
 114  87 104  33  82 138
 151  55 104  42 123 124
  87  41 173 131 134 179
```

**note:** C coding style generally favors all *lower-case* variable and function names, reserving all *upper-case* for constants and macros. Leave the *MixedCase* and *camelCase* names for java and C++. (it is style, so it is completely up to you, but...)